# HtmlUnit doesn't work on javascript processing

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I have tried almost all the methods mentioned in Stackoverflow, but none of them worked...

I'm trying to scraping following page using HtmlUnit:
http://www.nseindia.com/corporates/offerdocument/past_issue_document.htm

Just an empty page returned. It should be caused by javascript issue. I tried following tricks in HtmlUnit: waitForBackgroundJavaScript, refresh, redirect, sleep, enable javascript, click(true, true, true), etc. None of them worked...

Any suggestion:

my code:

```
String url = "http://www.nseindia.com/corporates/offerdocument/past_issue_document.htm";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8);
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);
this.getWebClient().waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Links to the other methods you've tried would be useful.

Comment: If the page uses ajax you may need `webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());`. This will cause the AJAX to block the call until it is completed.

Answer (score 1):

I had once similar issues. I workarounded it by using a firefox dev plugin, which logs all the requests the javascript page does. Then I emulated those requests directly from HtmlUnit (just grep the requests from the request log, paste them and inject sessionid misc parameters which are usually easy to identify. Especially useful when dealing with sites using a lot of ajax stuff.

Comment: Finally, I gave up to access it directly. Instead, I hijacked the response json file from their server and work on it. This India SE website really sucks! Always down!